# Opening InfoPath form from a SharePoint link

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have an infopath form (.xsn) and would like to open the form from the quick launch.
The link is like this (Ex): http://SharePoint/Forms/Test2.xsn

How can I add the .xsn page through the navigation property without getting Save/Open dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

Campbell,

Try this:

Under the registry key: [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.xsn], create a new string value called:
"Content Type" = "application/octet-stream"

This will not prompt you for the Save/Open Dialog.

I hope that helps!